# script to autoupdate IP in config file

Tags: sql, dynamic, scripting, ip

**Problem**

I have a SQL server that has a dynamic IP address. However I have a url e.g. 'mydynamic.com'
which is automatically updated to the current IP of the SQL server

**Requirement**

I need a script (vb/bat) that can take this URL and resolves the IP. Then take a config file and replace a placeholder with that IP. The idea is that the config file will always point to the correct IP.

Comment: Why don't you just use the domain in the config file?

Comment: I could try that, depends if it supports FQDN.

Comment: yeah, let us know and if not, then maybe someone has a script to do what you want (dns resolver script)

Comment: Tommy your suggestion worked, could you please post it and I can then mark it as answered? Perhaps write it up a bit generic in case other happen to search this topic area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most configuration files, you can either use an IP based or FQDN based approach to locating/connecting to your server.  If your IP is changing (ie dynamic), try placing the FQDN in place of the IP address so that DNS will do the resolution for you to your SQL server.